# Finding List A item pattern search in List B

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, pattern-matching

I am using a search pattern algorithm to find a pat(list) items in a txt(list). This function is supposed to return the index value of the list txt.

```
def search(pat, txt):
    M = len(pat)
    N = len(txt)
 
    # A loop to slide pat[] one by one */
    for i in range(N - M + 1):
        j = 0
 
        # For current index i, check
        # for pattern match */
        while(j < M):
            if (txt[i + j] != pat[j]):
                break
            j += 1
 
        if (j == M):
            print("Pattern found at index ", i)
 
 
# Driver's Code
txt = ["GA","07","09","07","0H"]
pat = ["GA","09","0H"]
for i in pat:
    for y in txt:
        if i == y:
            if __name__ == '__main__':
            # Function call
            search(pat, txt)
```

I have modified the above code. But this does not work. However, in the original code, if one item is provided to pat it works, and if more than one item is provided to pat, it collapses and does not show anython. Here is original code.

```
# Python3 program for Naive Pattern
# Searching algorithm
 
 
def search(pat, txt):
    M = len(pat)
    N = len(txt)
 
    # A loop to slide pat[] one by one */
    for i in range(N - M + 1):
        j = 0
 
        # For current index i, check
        # for pattern match */
        while(j < M):
            if (txt[i + j] != pat[j]):
                break
            j += 1
 
        if (j == M):
            print("Pattern found at index ", i)
 
 
# Driver's Code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    txt = ["GA","07","09","07","0H"]
    pat = ["07"]
     
    # Function call
    search(pat, txt)
```

Please provide more than one item to pat(list) and execute. I need this Naive search pattern algorithm to find all items of pat(list) in txt(list) and return index. For example

```
pat = ["GA","09","0H"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get index and item:

```
[list(filter(lambda item: item[1] == pat_item, enumerate(txt)))[0] for pat_item in pat]
```

- output:

  [(0, 'GA'), (2, '09'), (4, '0H')]

If you want to get just index:

```
[list(filter(lambda item: item[1] == pat_item, enumerate(txt)))[0][0] for pat_item in pat]
```

- output:

  [0, 2, 4]

Comment: Thank you. But I am doing some experiments using Naive Pattern Search. I need to find a pattern search using the above algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
indices = []
for x in pat:
    try:
        indices.append(txt.index(x))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Example with `txt = ['GA', '07', '09', '07', '0H']` and `pat = ['GA', '09', '0H']`:

```
>>> indices
[0, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks mate. But where do I call the function, If I call the function within for loop, it return nothing. If I call the function outside for loop, it only return index of first item.

Comment: @XiaoPi Can you provide me with your txt and pat lists? So that I can try my code to see if it's working. Also, please provide the expected output

Comment: lets say txt = ['0x70', '0x7f', '0xad', '0xd9', '0x7c', '0xda', '0xfe', '0xde', '0xfb'] and pat =  ['0x7f', '0xad', '0xd9', '0x7c', '0xda', '0xfe',] .............. out should be "["'0x7f'" pattern found at index 0, '0xad' pattern found at index 2, '0xd9' pattern found at index 3, '0x7c' pattern found at 4,  '0xda' found at index 5........... ]"

Comment: As mentioned above orignal code (Naive Pattern Search Algorithm), it works well. But it only take one item as input in pat(list).  I need to use above algorithm and suppose to have multiple items in pat(list)